Can a Pakistani citizen apply for a Mexican visa via the embassy in Abu Dhabi?
I am a Pakistani citizen and intend to apply for Mexican work permit. I have got the sponsor letter / offer letter but there is no Mexican embassy in  Pakistan. So can I get it from the Abu Dhabi Mexican embassy?
The reason I am asking is because one of my friend was not permitted to travel Mexico from Turkey. I don't know why turkish airline offloaded him from turkey. Can i get the reason why he was not allowed

You’ll have to get the reason your friend was offloaded from your friend. If he/she was self-transferring in Turkey, the most likely explanation is he/she did not have the correct paperwork for the onward flight to Mexico.

Per IATA Pakistani citizens may TWOV in Turkey through Ankara (ESB), Antalya (AYT), Istanbul: Metropolitan Area (IST) and Sabiha Gokcen (SAW), or Izmir (ADB) with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 24 hours. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next destination.
TWOV in Antalya (AYT) does not apply when transiting between terminals 1 & 2. The flights need to be booked as a single itinerary (ie one PNR).

It is better to call the Abu Dhabi embassy instead of just arriving. They should be able to help you though with the process. Typically for issues where there is no embassy or consulate in your home country, you go to the nearest one.
contactoeau@sre.gob.mx is the email to send enquiries to for the embassy in the United Arab Emirates.

Not just the geographically nearest one, but whichever the country was assigned to. It’s a good idea to contact an embassy to verify whether they deal with requests from a specific country or not.

There are two honorary consulates of Mexico in Pakistan. While they are not authorized to issue visas, they can certainly guide you on where you need to apply for the visa. The link is given below:
https://embamex.sre.gob.mx/iran/index.php/en/2016-05-27-11-35-32/honorary-consul
Regarding your friend being denied boarding, please note that you need both a Mexico visa for tourism and a Tourist Card, also known as the Forma Migratoria Múltiple (FMM). As per IATA website for Pakistani passport holders

Visa Exemptions: Passengers with a multiple-entry visa issued by
Canada, Japan, USA, United Kingdom or a Schengen Member State for a
maximum stay of 180 days.
Warning: Visitors not holding return/onward tickets could be refused
entry.

There have been many issues of people using the Mexico route to illegally cross into the US. In other cases I know of where people were denied boarding, it was because they weren't able to convince that they were legitimately going to Mexico - for instance, having booked a hotel for the number of days they will be staying, enough money, and a fully paid return ticket. Like the US, a Mexican visa only lets you go to Mexico but an immigration officer will decide to let you enter or not. Some basic requirements are checked by the airline so they do not have to bear the burden of deporting the passenger.
